# SwiftUI Как распарсить JSON с webSocket?

Tags: json, xcode, websocket, swiftui, json-encode

XCode SwiftUI Использую библиотеку Starscreem для работы с webSocket.
Получаю данные с сервера в таком виде:

text("{"time":1705559978736,"event":"push","team":1,"author":"Master OSX"}")

Подскажите пожалуйста как распарсить?
Спасибо!